# Inheritance model update to its parent model

Tags: python, django, django-inheritance

I need extend a model from another model.

Case:

*core/models.py*

```
class Master(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class City(Master):
        zipcode = models.IntegerField()
```

*custom/models.py*

```
from core.models import City
class City(City)
    newfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

custom is an app.

I have tried with proxy model but it is not what I need, since proxy model adds a new table. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

I need is that when I migrate add the new field to City.

> More info.
>   In core the table is created and in custom you can add new fields that the client needs. The idea is that core is only maintained as standard.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy models don't add new tables. From the [docs link you mentioned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models):

> The MyPerson class operates on the same database table as its parent Person class.

If you want one table called `core_city`, and another called `custom_city`, the second one having an extra field, you simply subclass it. Perhaps it would be easier to use an alias:

```
from core.models import City as CoreCity

class City(CoreCity):
    newfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

`custom_city` will have all fields from `core_city`, plus a `newfield`. The description of how this works (and an example) is covered in the docs section [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

If what you want is to have one **single database table**, then you should use a proxy Model, however they really don't allow you to create new fields. The field should be created in the parent model, or otherwise exist in the database and not be handled by Django migrations at all.

Comment: Master is the proxy model, just clarified it. It doesn't work this way because it creates a new table with the app suffix, and now I have two tables core_City and custom_City

Comment: Master is an abstract model; master.City is a proxy (proxy to what?). Sounds like master.City should be abstract too (see @dani herrera's answer).

Comment: City cannot be abstract because only when the client needs to add a new row will it be modified. The purpose is to create a core project with standard tables with standardized business logic and that only in customizations does the client add what he needs if that is the case.

Comment: Ok so stick to the second part of my answer, where it says "If what you want is to have one single database table...". Django can't make a migration to add a field in a proxy table. You can do it manually (for example with `migrations.RunSQL()`), but you will have to maintain it.

Comment: I have read about it but the problem is that if it is not declared in the model I will not be able to interact with the field.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) models:

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class.

This is the base class:

```py
#core/models.py
class City(Master):
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True   # <--- here the trick
```

Here your model:

```py
#custom/models.py
from core.models import City as CoreCity
class City(CoreCity):
    newfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

> For many uses, this type of model inheritance will be exactly what you want. It provides a way to factor out common information at the Python level, while still **only creating one database table per child model at the database level**.

Comment: City cannot be abstract table. For example client need one new row CityShortName,  to do that client need create a new app and customize there.

Comment: May be in same app, `abstract_models.py` and `models.py`. I do it here: https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/django-aula/tree/master/aula/apps/aules

Comment: Dani, in core the table is created and in customd you can add new fields that the client needs. The idea is that core is only maintained as standard.

Comment: Is the same as I do in example but with 2 apps instead just one. What I do is to write custom scheleton with `pass` as model body.

Comment: City cannot be abstract.

Comment: Take a look to https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/howto/how_to_customise_models.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198559/discussion-between-oegpyg-and-dani-herrera).

Answer (score 0):

You can update or create your class constants after its defined like this

```py
from core.models import City    

City.newfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: I tried but makemigrations doesn't detect the changes

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use swappable models, using them you can define a City class and change it with whichever model you need later,
but that way you can't import and use the base City model directly, you may need to provide a method like get_city_model for that, as your public API.

```
class City(Master):
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'CORE_CITY_MODEL'
```

and maybe replace it later with some other model, then just set CORE_CITY_MODEL to that model in the form of 'app_name.model_name'.

The django.contrib.auth is a good example of this, you may consider checking `User` model and `get_user_model` method. Although I think you may face problems if you change your city model after you did run migrate, it may not move your data to the new table, but I'm not sure about this.